# android SIP senddtmf - How to set DTMF delays

Tags: android, sip

I'm trying to find a way to change the way the DTMF is sent, but cannot find how to modify it. Are there any accessible parameters?
I need to have a DTMF signal of 100 ms second and then 200 ms of pause. 
If I stay in a loop doing wait, I can manage to have it symmetrical, but the receiver doesn't like it. It cannot receive the code properly in this case.

Without the loop on each char the receiver can hear only one sound, because it's sent too fast by android.

Comment: If you're doing the pause with a loop the output signal should be correct, shouldn't it? Could it be a problem with the receiver then?